# Prokhorov's theorem and bounded martingale convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory

My question is 2 parts:

1. What kind of standard tools are used in conjunction with Prokhorov's theorem? i.e. if I can find a weakly convergent subsequence of measures, what are common tricks to upgrade this to convergence of the whole sequence, and perhaps in a stronger sense?
2. The particular application I had in mind: it seems like there should be a two-line proof of the bounded martingale convergence theorem, but I do not know how to finish it. If a martingale $X_n$ is bounded, then the sequence of measures $\mu_n$ (where $\mu_n$ is the law of $X_n$) is trivially tight. So there is a weakly convergent subsequence. How do I upgrade this to weak (or stronger) convergence for the whole sequence?

Comment: One sufficient condition is existence of the point-wise limit of characterisitic functions.

Comment: Note that I did not assume in above comment that the limit functioin is a charactersitic function. This is a useful criterion in some situations.

Comment: There's no two-line proof of the bounded martingale convergence theorem, and you're not going to be able to upgrade tightness to a.s. convergence. I mean obviously you need to use the martingale property somewhere in the proof. It's pretty clearly **not** true that _every_ bounded sequence of random variables converges almost surely.